# accessing dict within dict value python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
tmpDict = {'ONE':{'TWO':{'THREE':10}}}
```

From this dictionary, how would would print the value 10? This is similar to a previously asked question, but they wanted to know how to add more values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(tmpDict['ONE']['TWO']["THREE"])
```

This is a general solution for all keys:

```
all_values = [tmpDict[i][j][k] for i in tmpDict.keys() for j in tmpDict[i].keys() for k in tmpDict[i][j].keys()]
print(all_values)
```

Comment: so this would not be possible then if I was trying to use a for loop to go through this and the 'TWO' value was different in each row?

Comment: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'  i get this error?

Comment: I have tried just now, it worked fine. Is there any mistake copying the code?

Comment: wait the problem is my dictionary is just this:

tmpDict = { 'one' : {'two' : 10}}

how would this change the coddE?

Comment: Simple remove loop for the third dict, like: `all_values = [tmpDict[i][j] for i in tmpDict.keys() for j in tmpDict[i].keys()]`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can navigate **nested dictionaries** in Python3 in the following way (`d` is your dictionary):

```
def traverse_nested_dict(d, parent_key='root'):
    """ Traverse dictionary and print keys and values
        :param d: a dictionary"""
    for key, value in d.items():
        current_key = parent_key+'.'+key
        if type(value) is dict:
            traverse_nested_dict(value, parent_key=current_key)
        else:
            print(f'{current_key} -> {value}')
```

for example:

```
my_dict = {'a': {'b': 3, 'c': {'d': 5}}}
traverse_nested_dict(my_dict)
```

will produce this output:

```
root.a.b -> 3
root.a.c.d -> 5
```

using your input:

```
tmpDict = {'ONE':{'TWO':{'THREE':10}}}
traverse_nested_dict(tmpDict)
```

you'll get:

```
root.ONE.TWO.THREE -> 10
```